# How do I merge a branche in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, branching-and-merging

I'm working with VS Code and using git and a local repository. From the master branche I created a new branche. In this new branched I implemented a new functionality. After implementing and testing I did a commit in my new branch, but now I want to merge this new branche in the master branche. How can I do this in VS Code?

Comment: I don't know VS Code at all, but the general strategy will be some sort of pull on the `master` branch, followed by a push to the `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Seems I need to merge from the terminal then. Hopefully it can be done in VS Code in the near future...